# How to scrape websites such as Hype Machine?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm curious about website scraping (i.e. how it's done etc..), specifically that I'd like to write a script to perform the task for the site [Hype Machine](http://hypem.com).
I'm actually a Software Engineering Undergraduate (4th year) however we don't really cover any web programming so my understanding of Javascript/RESTFul API/All things Web are pretty limited as we're mainly focused around theory and client side applications.
Any help or directions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's interesting to note that Hype Machine doesn't have a robots.txt, so it looks like they don't seem to mind anyone scraping.

Comment: Here's a blog post I wrote awhile back: [Web scraping in .NET](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2007/12/30/web_scraping_in_net).

Comment: that is interesting... I am curious in writing a script for myself to download the songs rather than having to visit the sites themselves...

Comment: I don't know what language you're looking for, but there are modules in many languages to scrape...in Python you can use BeautifulSoup4 (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I think you would definitely enjoy learning some web coding. You can, using Python and BeautifulSoup, scrape an entire website and then filter various elements out of it (like links...and then you could filter file types like mp3 data using regex matching etc etc)...however the how-to for this is a broader answer than which was initially posed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to look for is whether the site already offers some sort of structured data, or if you need to parse through the HTML yourself. Looks like there is an [RSS feed of latest songs](http://hypem.com/feed/time/today/1/feed.xml). If that's what you're looking for, it would be good to start there.

You can use a scripting language to download the feed and parse it. I use python, but you could pick a different scripting language if you like. Here's some docs on how you might [download a url in python](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and [parse XML in python](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_parse.html).

Another thing to be conscious of when you write a program that downloads a site or RSS feed is how often your scraping script runs. If you have it run constantly so that you'll get the new data the second it becomes available, you'll put a lot of load on the site, and there's a good chance they'll block you. Try not to run your script more often than you need to.

Comment: I seem to understand the scraping of the raw HTML data, I was also curious how one might scrape the songs for instance. I think their done via a Flash Player.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the following books:

"Webbots, Spiders, and Screen Scrapers: A Guide to Developing Internet Agents with PHP/CURL"
[http://www.amazon.com/Webbots-Spiders-Screen-Scrapers-Developing/dp/1593271204](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271204)

"HTTP Programming Recipes for C# Bots"
[http://www.amazon.com/HTTP-Programming-Recipes-C-Bots/dp/0977320677](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977320677)

"HTTP Programming Recipes for Java Bots"
[http://www.amazon.com/HTTP-Programming-Recipes-Java-Bots/dp/0977320669](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977320669)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the most important thing you must analyze is which kind of information do you want to extract. If you want to extract entire websites like google does probably your best option is to analyze tools like nutch from Apache.org or flaptor solution http://ww.hounder.org If you need to extract particular areas on unstructured data documents - websites, docs, pdf - probably you can extend nutch plugins to fit particular needs. nutch.apache.org

On the other hand if you need to extract particular text or clipping areas of a website where you set rules using DOM of the page probably what you need to check is more related to tools like mozenda.com. with those tools you will be able to set up extraction rules in order to scrap particular information on a website. You must take into consideration that any change on a webpage will give you an error on your robot.

Finally, If you are planning to develop a website using information sources you could purchase information from companies such as spinn3r.com were they sell particular niches of information ready to be consume. You will be able to save lots of money on infrastructure.
hope it helps!.
sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

Python has the feedparser module, located at feedparser.org that actually handles RSS in its various flavours and ATOM in its various flavours. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I actually had to scrape the HTML to get the secret keys for their API ;)